# Converting values from st_area() to square meters

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to find the area of a table in square meters. Note my spatial reference is in feet. 
My query is something like :

```
 update counties set t_as = st_area(the_geom)/1609.34^2;
```

So basically i am trying to convert a value like 507863856.33256 to square meters. I want the area to be values to be something like 4.2361524 instead of 507863856.33256.

update: The SRID is 2263

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the SRID used in your geometry column. The difference between square feet and square meters wont change your values by eight orders of magnitude,  just one.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: A google pulled up the conversion factor: `1 sq yd = 0.09290304 sq m`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 ft = 0.3048 meter

1 square ft = 0.3048 * 0.3048 = 0.092903 square meters

To convert square feet to square meter, you either have to multiply the value by 0.092903 or divide it by the inverse of this value (which is of course the same):

UPDATE counties SET t_as = ST_Area(the_geom) * 0.3048^2;

*or*

UPDATE counties SET t_as = ST_Area(the_geom) / (1 / 0.3048^2);

Either way, 507863856 square feet are 47182096 square meters. If you want to convert it to hectare or square kilometers, you have to divide the result by 10000 or 1000000 respectively.

Comment: And how about if i want to convert it to square miles?

Comment: "It" being the area.

Comment: Have you tried to google it? 1 mile are 5280 ft. So to convert square feet to square miles, just divide the area in square feet (in your case 507863856) by 5280^2 => 18.217 square miles.